# Nginx on Jelastic won't start

Tags: nginx, system-administration, jelastic

I'm starting a web app with nginx on Infomaniak (in ), and I have connections refused every time.

I found the issue, my Nginx service won't start, even after nodes restart.

Doing a `sudo service Nginx start` told me this

```
Starting nginx: nginx: [emerg] 
PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX("/var/lib/jelastic/SSL/jelastic.chain") failed 
(SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start 
line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
```

Comment: Is this happening on a newly provisioned node, or has this happened after some time? From the error it sounds like maybe related to custom SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Jelastic SSL**](https://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-ssl) is not supposed to work with an external IP.
After removing Jelastic SSL and changing `ssl.conf` to default - nginx will start without any problems.
If you want to use an external IP and ssl certificate we suggest you installing Free Let’s Encrypt SSL Certificate, [here](https://jelastic.com/blog/free-ssl-certificates-with-lets-encrypt/) you can find detailed step by step instruction